# Is it safe to have public read access on Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My website accesses a Firebase Realtime Database to get non-sensitive data (detail below) and display it publicly.
I only need to be able to write data from the Firebase console.

My question is, are there any security risks
in having my database rules as so:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

I am brand new to leveraging cloud services so any extra advice is appreciated.

Extra detail: the data is a list of past clients for a music producer, I am using the DB because he wants to be able to update the list when he gets new clients using the Firebase Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's safe if you don't mind anyone with an internet connection to be able to read the entire contents of your database.

Security rules don't affect the way anything works with data entry in the Firebase console.

Comment: There's nothing in it that isn't displayed on the site itself, so should be alright. Thanks!